# VK API отправка сообщений с сайта в сообщество

Tags: vkontakte-api, angular2, angular6

Есть Angular приложение, в котором есть форма, где формируется текстовое сообщение. Необходимо оиправить это сообщение в сообщество вконтакте (всем администраторам) как это можно реализовать с помощью vk API? Изучил документацию, не нашел ничего подходящего

Comment: `API` сообщений очень сильно ограничили. Уточните, пожалуйста, как Вы авторизуетесь (например, токеном сообщества)?

Comment: Пока никак, но да, наверное токеном сообщества, тк этот вариант больше всего подходит (приложение связано с сообществом ВК)